# Determine the current filename located in Windows Azure Storage via C#

Tags: c#, azure, streamreader

I'd like to know how to determine the current filename, located in Windows Azure Blobstorage, one is processing at runtime in C# code?

I'm using StreamReader to process .txt files, and I'd like to know the name of the file I'm currently processing.

Comment: Include your code that opens the file stream

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you stop thinking of the blob as an actual file. The "file name" in blob terms is everything in the path for the object that occurs after the container name...

```
http://<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<container-name>/<blob-name>
```

Now the "blob name" could be something like "myfile/onaday/file.txt". While it appears there's a directory structure in place, this is really just a client side semantic that can be leveraged. But to the storage service, the entire string is the name. You can also change the default delimiter from '/' to another character. This really drives home the face that the hierarchy is simply a client/consumer side construct.

Now all that said, if you're just trying to get "file.txt", you have two options IMHO. 
1) store this attribute as a metadata tag on the blob when its created/uploaded to blob storage. 
2) parse the value from the URI, using various native language methods, or perhaps just looking for the final delimiter ('/') and taking everything that occurs after it.